# edit efivars on MacOSX

Tags: efi

On Linux, I can edit the efivars of my MacBookPro via `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/`. E.g. [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/force-2011-macbook-pro-8-2-with-failed-amd-gpu-to-always-use-intel-integrated-gpu-efi-variable-fix.2037591/) is a description to disable the AMD GPU via the efivars, which basically is this on Linux:

```
printf "\x07\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00" > /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/gpu-power-prefs-fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9
```

Is it possible to edit the efivars directly on MacOSX? I still can sometimes boot to OSX, so I wonder if I need to use Linux for this or if I can directly edit them with some OSX tools.

(Related questions: [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70283/how-to-permanently-disable-defective-graphics-card-in-macbook-pro), [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen/295805#295805))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

Full access to all efivars is not that feasible or easy in macOS / from OS X.

But if you want to achieve the goals from the link and command you cited then go here please: [GPU problem - Boot Hangs on Grey Screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295805/251859)

There you will find the equivalent for a pure Mac environment:

```
nvram fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9:gpu-power-prefs=%01%00%00%00
```

Read the whole guide, though. It's still a bit of a dance to apply that variable and manage the consequences of it.