# Macbook Pro 15" (Early 2011) Black screen on boot

Tags: macbook-pro, display, startup, gpu

Hope there is someone that can help me, i've tried EVERYTHING. A week ago my other MBP broke, so I knew I had the old 2011 one, but when I charged it up and booted, nothing happened...the computer made the sound that it's on but nothing came on the screen, completely black. I took it to Apple repair shop, there they told me that the problem is in GPU. I googled it A LOT and it seems that it's a common problem with the 2011 MBP's. I read somewhere that it has 2 GPUS, one is the AMD and other is Intel Graphics and the AMD one is with the problem, so I even tried to change the GPU from AMD to Intel on boot, but it's quite hard to do when the screen is black and you can't see anything. Also tried to connect to external monitor so maybe I could see something through that, but nope, says 'No Signal' on monitor.

Is there anything else to do or is the only way to change the Logic Board?
Thanks.

Comment: Please specify what you did. "Everything" does not help us, since we don't know what error sources you already excluded with your tests. Changing the logic board probably won't help either, since - as you mention as well - it is very likely a GPU problem (so you'd have to change the dedicated GPU).

Comment: Yeah, sorry. So I have tried everything from here, but not sure If I even did something since I can't see, but I tried... https://gist.github.com/cdleon/d1eff7246a25193304284ecec40445b0 
Also tried forcing MBP to use Intel Graphics, tried the blanket wrapping thing on youtube. Really thought the defective GPU fix would help, since usually it's the AMD gpu that stops working and Intel GPU is fine, but nothing helped. Tried disconnecting the battery and SSD/HDD, didn't help.

Comment: Are you aware that some commands on that GitHub guide need to be executed from the terminal? I don't see how you'd be able to do that with no working screen. Also, is the Apple sign lighting up on the back? And further check this link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70283/how-to-permanently-disable-defective-graphics-card-in-macbook-pro. Can you boot from a different drive?

Comment: Oh, that I didn't know. Sorry I really don't know what I'm doing, just trying to get it to work. The apple logo on the back is not lighting up, can't see anything on the screen with flashlight throught apple logo also.

Comment: Apple Logo on the back not lighting means there is no power for the screen. It really seems like a hardware issue and there is not much we can do. If you know what you are doing you could open the MacBook and look for obvious damage. But - and since you say yourself you don't know what you're doing - I highly recommend finding an independent repair shop, they will help you out.

Comment: That's weird, because If I took it to Apple Authorized shop for diagnostics they told me that the problem is in gpu. Also if there's no power for the screen shouldn't it work when I connect HDMI to it? Also opened the MB already, removed logic board and everything but didn't see anything no water damage or nothing, idk. But thank you for answering and trying to help!